# Media Queries not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

I am currently creating my portfolio website in WordPress at [www.yewtreeweb.co.uk](http://www.yewtreeweb.co.uk). However I am having a problem with getting media queries to work in Internet Explorer 11.

When I add the media queries the style does not display in the inspect element console of  Internet Explorer however BootStrap's media queries do appear. Is it something to do with WordPress or am I doing something wrong?

Also my styling does work if out of the media query.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
      @media screen and (min-width: 64.000em){
            #imgholder-left{
                padding-right: 0;
             }
            #imgholder-right{
                padding-left: 0;
             }
             #leftimg > img {
                 width: 400px;
              }
              #rightimg > img {
                 width: 600px;
              }
         }
     }
```

Comment: I don't think you can nest media queries

Comment: Nested media queries *are* allowed in [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing) (but not 2.1)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

instead

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    ...
}
```

use this

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
    ... 
}
```

Comment: OR because it is min-width 1024 just make the default css for the site and leave off the media query...

Comment: Hi Vitorino thank you for youe help. The query displays in IE11 now  thank you. However it doesn't really work as it still applies the styling when the resolution is under 1024px and doesn't show at all when changed to max

Comment: also change @ media screen to @ media all to the nested one (min-width: 64.000em)

Comment: Thanks for your help Vitorino, it now works =D . I had to remove the nested and change screen to all. I hate IE don't understand why only all seems to work

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Although nested media queries *are* allowed in [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing) (but not 2.1) I can imagine that this is exactly the sort of thing that has cross-browser issues.

I don't understand why you are testing min-width twice but consider putting them in the same query, [comma-separated to signify an OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px), screen and (min-width: 64.000em) {
    //if *either* of these are matched then apply these rules
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Moob. It was just how I was taught at University to nest em into the query.