# Media queries: orientation landscape and horizontal doesn't work at IE 11 (desktop and mobile)

Tags: media-queries, orientation, internet-explorer-11

https://jsbin.com/lapupe/25/edit?html,css,output
Hi (sorry for my english) there's a bit of code which works at chrome, firefox, safari(mobile and desktop) but at IE(mobile and desktop 11) doesn't. Could you help me with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Media Queries not working in Internet Explorer 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059414/media-queries-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: @doru, I've seen this post already, but there is no answer for me

Comment: my problem is fixed(on another forum), ( orientation : landscape ) should be written  (orientation : landscape) - without this spaces.

Comment: @Kalina I ran into this, too; your note about spaces saved me. They work fine in Firefox and Chrome, but of _course_ IE has to be "special"...